# Javascript - Traverse A Tree To Generate The Sequence Of The Nodes

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree-traversal, treepath

I have found few SO questions relevant to this but none of them were based on the exact problem I am trying to solve.

Basically, I am working on a tree structure and every node is assigned an id.

The objective is to generate a sequence string that will provide a path to traverse the entire tree sequentially.

As an example the output of following diagram should be **123242523637321**

---

[image]

---

As you can see, the tree starts at node 1 and then goes to node 2.

Node 2 is connected to 3 other nodes viz. node 3, node 4 & node 5.

Following the sequence, the next node is 3.

To go to the next node i.e. node 4, we will have to go back to node 2 and then go to node 4, so the string becomes **12324**

Once we get the last node i.e. node 7, we will go back to the first node and hence the string ends with a substring **7321**

I am trying to construct a logic that would generate the string from a given tree structure.

Sample tree structure for above diagram is -

---

```
const sequenceObj = {
    1: {
        id: "Point_1cec2262-20f8-4985-adcb-b6d95a618d22",
        connectedNodes: ["2"]
    },
    2: {
        id: "Point_02bdae16-1cdb-48e1-a601-7b1e526eedb8",
        connectedNodes: ["1", "3", "4", "5"]
    },
    3: {
        id: "Point_55a68ac0-17ef-48a2-bf9f-c70004a27d99",
        connectedNodes: ["2", "6", "7"]
    },
    4: {
        id: "Point_8760427c-98bb-4e3e-85dd-59cba3b31c6f",
        connectedNodes: ["2"]
    },
    5: {
        id: "Point_79a7bcec-d110-43dc-b9ac-1552538bc1a5",
        connectedNodes: ["2"]
    },
    6: {
        id: "Point_37550cf0-4bd5-48b2-b32f-9018bd55c05f",
        connectedNodes: ["3"]
    },
    7: {
        id: "Point_2de67998-9e1f-4b06-af18-77d558d68254",
        connectedNodes: ["3"]
    }
};
```

---

As you can see, every node has a property called connectedNodes which helps us traverse the tree.

---

> EDIT - As pointed out in comments, the property **connectedNodes** (*which was previously called children*) stores the ids of connected nodes.
> The provided object does not represent the tree, we only need to use this object to traverse from start to end i.e. from id 1 to 7 in this example.

---

Let me know if I have missed something or if more information is required.

Thanks!

Comment: Your input appears incorrect. `2: { children: [ "1", "3", "4", "5" ] }`, why does `1` appear as a child of `2`? Why does `2` appears as a child of `4`, `5`? Why is `3` a child of `6` and `7`? This doesn't make sense

Comment: @Thankyou Apologies for using incorrect naming conventions. The property children is storing ids of all the connected nodes (which is what I am getting as an API response. I think calling it `connectedNodes` would make more sense. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is written in a that nodes list their parents as `children`. We fix that first -

```js
const node = (id, ...children) =>
  ({ constructor: node, id, children })

const tree =
  node(1, node(2, node(3, node(7), node(6)), node(4), node(5)))
```

Now we can write your `traverse` -

```js
function* traverse(t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case node:
      yield t.id
      for (const c of t.children)
      { yield *traverse(c)
        yield t.id
      }
  }
}
```

```js
for (const v of traverse(tree))
  console.log(v)
```

```js
1
2
3
7
3
6
3
2
4
2
5
2
1
```

Or we can collect them all in one string

```js
console.log(Array.from(traverse(tree)).join(""))
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const node = (id, ...children) =>
  ({ constructor: node, id, children })

function* traverse(t)
{ switch (t?.constructor)
  { case node:
      yield t.id
      for (const c of t.children)
      { yield *traverse(c)
        yield t.id
      }
  }
}

const tree =
  node(1, node(2, node(3, node(7), node(6)), node(4), node(5)))

console.log(Array.from(traverse(tree)).join(""))
```

```js
1237363242521
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take seen nodes out of the children array and get the nodes of unseen keys.

```js
const
    getSequence = (key, seen = {}) => {
        seen[key] = true;

        const unseen = sequenceObj[key]
                .children
                .filter(k => !seen[k]);

        return unseen.length
            ? `${key}${unseen.flatMap(k => getSequence(k, seen)).join(key)}${key}`
            : key;
    },
    sequenceObj = { 1: { id: "Point_1cec2262-20f8-4985-adcb-b6d95a618d22", children: ["2"] }, 2: { id: "Point_02bdae16-1cdb-48e1-a601-7b1e526eedb8", children: ["1", "3", "4", "5"] }, 3: { id: "Point_55a68ac0-17ef-48a2-bf9f-c70004a27d99", children: ["2", "6", "7"] }, 4: { id: "Point_8760427c-98bb-4e3e-85dd-59cba3b31c6f", children: ["2"] }, 5: { id: "Point_79a7bcec-d110-43dc-b9ac-1552538bc1a5", children: ["2"] }, 6: { id: "Point_37550cf0-4bd5-48b2-b32f-9018bd55c05f", children: ["3"] }, 7: { id: "Point_2de67998-9e1f-4b06-af18-77d558d68254", children: ["3"] } };

console.log(getSequence('1'));
```